# Can you add your athletics score to defense multiple times?

Tags: combat, scion

Under "defensive do-over", it states that you can spend one legend point to add half your athletics score to your defense retroactively. Can you activate this multiple times on one attack until you end up having dodged it?

Comment: Is this the White Wolf or the Onyx Path editions?

Comment: First edition. A quick check reveals second edition isn't out yet.

Comment: Reason asking is there are no longer updates from White Wolf.

Comment: Ok? I'm not sure why that matters?

Comment: Many people have subscriptions to White Wolf media via online resources. So there may be an update from Onyx Path that won't be reflected on older White Wolf media.

Comment: Isn't that true of all white wolf rpg properties? Onyx path is the new licensed publisher for world of darkness and owns scion outright, that's been true for a while now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It would require a Storyteller's interpretation.

RAW states:

> Defensive Do-over: By spending one Legend point, the player of an attacked character may retroactively increase his character's Defense Value against a successful attack by an amount equal to his (Athletics ÷ 2). The player can do so only after the attacker's player makes his attack roll.

There is no mention that you can only use the power once per attacker's attack, such as how rerolling a failed action once per failed action does:

> Rerolling an action: The player may spend one Legend point to reroll a failed action, even if the action resulted in a botch. This ability is most cost effective when used to reroll exceptionally difficult actions or stunts. Only one reroll may be attempted per failed action.

## Opinion

It may not be gamebreaking - since you would pour through your Legend Points very quickly if used in such a manner. Speak with the storyteller and come to an agreement.

**Source**

Scion: Hero (White Wolf Publishing)